# Run a notebook from different directory in another notebook in Jupyter Lab Domino

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ibm-domino

I am trying to run `notebook_torun.ipynb` in `test_notebook.ipynb`  within Jupyter Lab Domino from a different directory but have failed. The structure looks as such:

```
root -> mnt -> test_notebook.ipynb
```

and I want to run

```
root -> repos -> test-directory -> notebook_torun.ipynb.
```

My attempt looks as such:

```
%run ../repos/test-directory.notebook_torun.ipynb
```

However everytime the command seems to append `.py` on the end so the error is `File ../repos/test-directory.notebook_torun.ipynb.py not found.`

Is there anyway to stop this behaviour so that it knows it is a notebook? Thanks

Comment: About "Is there anyway to stop this behavior so that it knows it is a notebook?" : It's adding the `.py` in a last ditch effort to deal with your bad path. If you properly point at the notebook file it won't do that behavior. Is `test-directory.notebook_torun.ipynb` a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following inside `test_notebook.ipynb`?

```py
%run ../repos/test-directory/notebook_torun.ipynb
```

Or if you want to use the absolute path, you can use this if root is the same as home (it may not be though, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165783).):

```py
%run ~/repos/test-directory/notebook_torun.ipynb
```

You should be able to test and develop all this using `ls` (or `%cd` and `pwd`, with `%cd ~/mnt` to switch back to original location of your `test_notebook.ipynb`,) **inside your notebook**.